# How to run docker image using kubectl cmd with specific cmd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, wiremock

I used to run wiremock image using flowing ***docker run*** cmd :

```
docker run -it -p 8787:8787 rodolpheche/wiremock --port 8787 --verbose
```

Now I am trying to run it in Kubernetes using ***kubectl run*** cmd, the following one is running successfully

```
kubectl run wiremock --image=rodolpheche/wiremock
```

but I am not able to run it with custom cmd "--port 8787 --verbose", I also tried the below option but I couldn't run [wiremock](https://hub.docker.com/r/rodolpheche/wiremock) container with these specific options "--port 8787 --verbose"

```
# Start container using a different command and custom arguments.
kubectl run wiremock --image=rodolpheche/wiremock --command -- <cmd> <arg1> ... <argN>
```

is there any way to run it in Kubernetes on port 8787 with the verbose option?

Comment: create yml file and then try,  ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/

Comment: also check port status `netstat -tunlp | grep 8787`, if its listening then pod will not create. also check log messages for any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kubectl run wmock --image rodolpheche/wiremock --port 8787 -- --port 8787 --verbose
```

should do the trick, this will create a single pod with wiremock running on port 8787 with the verbose flag:

```
k exec -it wmock -- /bin/bash
root@wmock:/home/wiremock#
...
root@wmock:/home/wiremock# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.4  1.9 3370684 78964 ?       Ssl  18:37   0:02 java -cp /var/wiremock/lib/*:/var/wiremock/extensions/* com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --port 8787 --verbose
```

Comment: The port-forward was not working, I had to run manually "kubectl port-forward wmock  8787:8787"